# How to Do 10-fold cross-validation with a test set size of in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation

How to build a machine learning model for predicting the expected `SpendValue` for a customer Using the `LinearRegression()` function

Also measure the performance of the model using 10-fold cross-validation with a test set size of 20%.

[image]

```
X = sales.drop(['SpendValue'], axis=1).values
y = sales.SpendValue.values
print("The training dataset has {} examples and {} features.".format(X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
lr = LinearRegression()
kfolds = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=False)
for train, test in kfolds.split(X):
    print("Train Index: ", train, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test)
```

I am not sure where to mention the test Size and how to proceed further to Predict the expected `Spendvalue` for the customer and also to display the various performance measures

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i have  added the complete question now

Answer (score 0):

I would like to start the explanation of cross validation and train & test splitting, which was explained [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

[image]

First, you have to do the train-test splitting (something like the following)

```
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

Then do a cross validation of training dataset and also you have a test dataset of size 20% of the original dataset.

```
kfolds = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=False)
for train, test in kfolds.split(X_train):
    print("Train Index: ", train, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test)
```